Is it possible to use listBuilder class without entity
I would like to know if it's possible to use a class extending list builder to build a list. My goal is to add a new groupRelationship type to a group type using GroupRelationType, and have the possiblity to build a list of relationships with some complex behaviors (for example the ability to have a "sub-content" for each item of the list).
Using views seems to be painful for my purpose. I can maybe use a controller or a form but if list builder can be used it would be nice.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Maybe the Subgroup module can fit your needs. As for the question in the title, I would say almost definitely not, as it's an entity API, but I have not looked into it.

This is a pluggable part of the entity API so that you can change how an entity type builds its listing. What value do you expect from an entity list builder other than that? You can just put the code creating a list in a controller for data not contained in entities.

Yes @Jaypan it's entity API. Group / group relationships are entities. But the way group allow to extend group-relationship plugins can't allow to build own entities, only extending GroupRelationType with annotations instead of building new group-relationships with all needs.
I saw that each group entity lists allowed as link tasks are views (members, nodes).
But Jaypan and 4uk4 answered the question. ListBuilders are defined for entities. For my needs, I'm implementing a form.
